# Mysql selecting the greatest difference between rows

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a fairly large table that is updated regularly with new data that sort of looks like this:

```
id  |  name  |  c1  |  c2  |  c3  |  c4  |  time
-------------------------------------------------
 1  |  miley |  23  |  11  |  21  |  18  |  2013-01-13 20:26:25
 2  |  john  |  31  |  29  |  23  |  27  |  2013-01-13 20:26:25
 3  |  steve |  44  |  31  |  33  |  35  |  2013-01-13 20:26:25
 4  |  miley |  34  |  44  |  47  |  48  |  2013-01-14 08:26:25
 5  |  john  |  27  |  53  |  49  |  52  |  2013-01-14 08:26:25
 6  |  steve |  27  |  62  |  50  |  64  |  2013-01-14 08:26:25
 7  |  miley |  44  |  54  |  57  |  87  |  2013-01-14 20:26:25
 8  |  john  |  37  |  93  |  59  |  62  |  2013-01-14 20:26:25
 9  |  steve |  85  |  71  |  87  |  74  |  2013-01-14 20:26:25
...etc
```

I need a query to find who had the biggest difference for each column for each day. (for example on the 14th - steve has the biggest increase in c1 and c3, john has c2, and miley has c4). Each person's numbers are always increasing, so it can be assumed that the first entry on any day for any person will always be less than their last entry that day.

I've tried working out a few queries with little success and not much to go on, if someone could at least point me in the right direction?

Desired output would ideally be an array of each row containing the name and difference that had the biggest increase. I'm not sure all this could be done in one query, but really all I need is the name of the person who had the biggest increase for each column and what their difference was.

.

**breakdown**

I need to grab the first and last entry for for every person on the 14th (id: 4 thru 9); compare the difference between their c1 values, return the name of the person who has the greatest difference. Repeat for c2, c3, & c4.

---

What I have so far thanks to orangecrush, only attempting to get 1 column: (error: invalid use of group function)

```
        "SELECT nm, diff_c1 FROM (
         SELECT NAME nm, MAX(c1) - MIN(c1) DIFF_C1 FROM TABLE AS a
             WHERE `time` > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
             GROUP BY NAME) AS c 
         WHERE diff_c1 = (
         (SELECT max(MAX(c1) - MIN(c1)) FROM TABLE AS b 
         WHERE `time` > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) GROUP BY NAME)
         )"
```

Comment: what will be your desired output?

Comment: What I notice is that on 14th, John has the largest difference in c1 and c3.

Comment: edited my question to include output, sorry if I'm not being clear I'm not exactly sure what kind of query I need to use here

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT nm, 'c1', diff_c1
  FROM (SELECT NAME nm, MAX(C1) - MIN(C1) DIFF_C1
          FROM TEST
         WHERE trunc(TIME) = '14-JAN-2013'
         GROUP BY NAME)
 WHERE diff_c1 = ((SELECT max(MAX(C1) - MIN(C1))
                     FROM TEST
                    WHERE trunc(TIME) = '14-JaN-2013'
                    GROUP BY NAME))
union
SELECT nm, 'c2', diff_c2
  FROM (SELECT NAME nm, MAX(C2) - MIN(C2) DIFF_C2
          FROM TEST
         WHERE trunc(TIME) = '14-JaN-2013'
         GROUP BY NAME)
 WHERE diff_c2 = ((SELECT max(MAX(C2) - MIN(C2))
                     FROM TEST
                    WHERE trunc(TIME) = '14-JaN-2013'
                    GROUP BY NAME))
union
SELECT nm, 'c3', diff_c3
  FROM (SELECT NAME nm, MAX(C3) - MIN(C3) DIFF_C3
          FROM TEST
         WHERE trunc(TIME) = '14-JaN-2013'
         GROUP BY NAME)
 WHERE diff_c3 = ((SELECT max(MAX(C3) - MIN(C3))
                     FROM TEST
                    WHERE trunc(TIME) = '14-JaN-2013'
                    GROUP BY NAME))
union
SELECT nm, 'c4', diff_c4
  FROM (SELECT NAME nm, MAX(C4) - MIN(C4) DIFF_C4
          FROM TEST
         WHERE trunc(TIME) = '14-JaN-2013'
         GROUP BY NAME)
 WHERE diff_c4 = ((SELECT max(MAX(C4) - MIN(C4))
                     FROM TEST
                    WHERE trunc(TIME) = '14-JaN-2013'
                    GROUP BY NAME))
```

Have hardcoded the dates. This can be dynamically called later, if this query is found to be working. Table name that I used for testing: TEST.

Comment: I need to select the biggest difference by user for a specific date, not the max value of a column

Comment: Deleted my answer after seeing this. I completely misunderstood. I thought he was looking for the greatest difference between *seperate* columns.

Comment: Aren't c1, c2, c3 and c4 differences? If not, what are the two entities from which the difference is being taken from? Coz when you say, `on the 14th - steve has the biggest increase in c1 and c3, john has c2, and miley has c4)`, I see that the max values from c1, c2, c3 and c4 are the names that you have mentioned to each of those columns.

Comment: But the max value won't always mean the biggest change.

Comment: Correct, max value won't mean biggest change. I updated my question a bit, please let me know if it makes more sense. Each column is recording a different value, I need to determine who has the greatest value change for each column by day.

Comment: I think I understood the question and the result that was required. Have modified the query. Please run and let me know if it works.

Comment: For now I just want to get one column so I've ignored the unions and get the error "Every derived table must have its own alias." I tried adding aliases to the tables and defining all columns but I still get the same error

Comment: *fixed ^ error - now getting the error "invalid use of group function." I'll edit my first post with what i have

Comment: The query that I built was in Oracle DB. For mysql, the syntax might been to be tweaked.

Comment: Use GREATEST(), add partition by date to your query. 
mysql> SELECT GREATEST(34.0,3.0,5.0,767.0);
        -> 767.0